How can I upload files to a submission using the REST API?
I am trying to upload PDF files to webform submission using REST API.
I used webform rest module rest webful service module to add content in the webform, i am able to add content but unable to add the file using the same way as adding file in node.
I tried using /webform_rest/{webform_id}/upload/{field_name} but this API is not available for post.

Does this answer your question? Unable to upload files through RESTful services
